# Python vscode formatter to keep upto 3 args in a line and split it no fewer

Tags: python, vscode-extensions, formatter, autopep8, python-black

I want so format my `python code` in `vscode` for function|class definitions, with a formatter obeying these 2 criteria for splitting into new line:

1. the line has exceeded 40 characters
2. the line has exceeded 3 args in a line

### criteria 1 illustration

if the line is longer it should split so:

```
def longerFunctionName(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5): #// assume character length limit is 30
```

would be

```
def longerFunctionName(arg1,
    arg2, arg3, arg4, 
    arg5):
```

### criteria 2 illustration

so if a line in a definitions has 4 args, after the 3rd one should be splitted like

```
def func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
```

should be

```
def func(arg1, arg2, arg3, 
    arg4):
```

### tries

in `settings.json` I have tried:

```
"[python]": {
  "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
    "--max-line-length=40",
    "--indent-size=4",
    "--indent-after-paren=1",
    "--aggressive",
    "--max-args=3"
  ]
}
```

or

```
"[python]": {
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": ["-l", "40"],
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
}
```

which don't work as I want;

1. with 79 char limit changes

```
def skmfdskmkfn_kfdks_kfmdckdsmk(dfkekrm=["df", "dfdnfkmem"], dfkekrm2=["df", "dfdnfkmem"], dfkekrm3=["df", "dfdnfkmem"],):
    dfkekrm3
```

to

```
def skmfdskmkfn_kfdks_kfmdckdsmk(
    dfkekrm=["df", "dfdnfkmem"],
    dfkekrm2=["df", "dfdnfkmem"],
    dfkekrm3=["df", "dfdnfkmem"],
):
    dfkekrm3
```

note it could have kept some args in one line till 80 character. like

```
def skmfdskmkfn_kfdks_kfmdckdsmk(dfkekrm=["df", "dfdnfkmem"],
    dfkekrm2=["df", "dfdnfkmem"], dfkekrm3=["df", "dfdnfkmem"],):
    dfkekrm3
```

2. even don't work in case of more than 3 args

```
def longerFunctionName(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
    arg1
```

note keeps the following unchanged but it was supposed to split after 3 args